# I’m working with pcf7991at antenna driver ic

Tags: ac, inductor, sine, coupling

[image]Just wondering if you can help me I’m trying to calculate capacitor and resistor values for a 125khz inductor coil . My coil measures 6.8 ohms. I’m not sure how to calculate the capacitor values between the ic drive pins and antenna coil wire to create a perfect sine wave

Comment: What will be the question if we say we can help? Ask that question directly, with info why are you unsure how to calculate it and what help you need to calculate it, instead of asking if we can help.

Comment: You’ll need to know the inductance of your coil as the capacitor needs to form a resonant circuit to create a sine wave. In reality there is no such thing as a ‘perfect sine wave’, so let go of that expectation.

Comment: How do I calculate or measure the inductance of my coil only thing I know how to do is measure the ohms with a multimeter?

Comment: You need to measure it with an inductance measurement tool. If you don't have one or can't rely on any other data on the coil, you can't calculate capacitance for obtaining peak performance at 125 kHz.

Comment: thank you i will have to purchase a lcr meter and measure the inductance of the coil im working with before i can ask for more help in calculating the values in my circuit